# Chrome crashes with segmentation fault in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: kernel, google-chrome, crash, segmentation-fault

I have a machine equipped with a core i7, AMD Radeon RX580 and 8GB ram. I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 and have been experiencing some weird issues with some applications: Firefox crashes continually to the point where it is pretty much unusable. I installed chrome-stable and I can run it fine for 30 min than it crashes. When I look ad the /var/log/kern.log I see a segmentation fault error that pertains to chrome processes. I tried to reinstall but the problem persists. Here is the kernel log:

```
Mar  3 12:45:55 lucky kernel: [ 3545.730030] chrome[6040]: segfault at cc7a4acdb00 ip 0000562e14dbd502 sp 00007ffea6e59070 error 4 in chrome[562e0fade000+686c000]

Mar  3 12:45:58 lucky kernel: [ 3548.421891] TaskSchedulerFo[6118]: segfault at 129911f00008 ip 0000562e11531181 sp 00007fd762c77360 error 4 in chrome[562e0fade000+686c000]

Mar  3 12:46:38 lucky kernel: [ 3588.153690] TaskSchedulerFo[6470]: segfault at 0 ip 0000562e112d5a0e sp 00007fd7610dacd0 error 4 in chrome[562e0fade000+686c000]

Mar  3 12:46:38 lucky kernel: [ 3588.525893] TaskSchedulerFo[6056]: segfault at 39 ip 000055db852c70b0 sp 00007f8bddbf4fe8 error 6 in chrome[55db85031000+686c000]

Mar  3 12:51:09 lucky kernel: [ 3859.589685] chrome[6586]: segfault at 39 ip 0000555f73b7e0b0 sp 00007ffc8263b7c8 error 6 in chrome[555f738e8000+686c000]

Mar  3 12:54:21 lucky kernel: [ 4051.705741] chrome[9843]: segfault at 1001c ip 000055b95d72bdd1 sp 00007fff439b7410 error 4 in chrome[55b9583c6000+686c000]

Mar  3 13:02:51 lucky kernel: [ 4561.904082] chrome[9558]: segfault at 100000000000 ip 000055b95d0ea5a1 sp 00007fff439b73d0 error 4 in chrome[55b9583c6000+686c000]
```

Has anyone experienced something similar? Does this maybe suggest faulty hardware?

Answer (score 2):

Fixed my problem!

After trying numerous things, finally decided to play around with the hardware. I switched my RAM for another chip and that fixed my problem. It looks like the old RAM was physically damaged.